# EditText's onDraw canvas gets shifted to the left when single line is set

Tags: android, canvas, android-edittext

I have a very simple customized EditText like this:

```
public class MyEditText extends EditText {
    private Paint mPaint;

    public MyEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        setSingleLine();

        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(6);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        int y = canvas.getHeight() * 6 / 7;
        canvas.drawLine(0, y, canvas.getWidth(), y, mPaint);
    }
}
```

As I set single line mode on, when text is short everything is fine, it would look like this:

[image]

But once the text gets longer (more than width of the EditText), the red line is shifted to the left like this:

[image]

As you'll probably notice I used 0 and canvas.getWidth() to connect both sides of the view, but the line gets shifted, so doesn't it mean the whole canvas gets shifted as well?

If so it's such a strange behavior that I didn't expect from a View descendant. Can someone shed me some light on this strange behavior?

Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Change your `onDraw()` method like below...

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Rect r = new Rect();
        int baseline = getLineBounds(0, r);
        int y = canvas.getHeight() * 6 / 7;
        canvas.drawLine(r.left, y, r.right, y, mPaint);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
```

Comment: It's not just i want to draw a line under the text, but I want to know why the canvas gets shifted, because I planed to draw icons at the beginning and end of the EditText. By the way, when singleLine is set, the returned rect by getLineBounds is always the same, especially `r.right` is always a same very big number

Comment: What do you want exactly??

Comment: I want to draw a underline and also an icon at beginning and another at the end of the EditText(like setDrawable start and end). But the problem is I want to animate them as well!!! I checked source code of TextView in the ASOP, it seems the canvas is translated to fit the view port of the scroll, I'm not sure.

Comment: Can you share the reference image so that I can understand what you want exactly?

Comment: Okay, look at the search bar of Facebook app for Android phone, type something in it you will see the X button on the right, press it you will see scale down then disappear animation. I want that plus before search view is opened, I want it to be collapsed into a search icon that acts like a search button as well. And for the sake of performance and compatibility with other components in my activity, I don't want to use a LinearLayout which container 2 ImageViews and 1 EditText (I tried, too complex to animate smoothly)

Comment: What you tried to animate the X button...can you share the code?

Comment: I used `view.animate().scale(0).alpha(0)` and such, it's simple but I combine 3 or 4 animations at once, it wasn't smooth enough on some phones. Besides, it was complex to restore animated state after activity get killed by the system. So there were too many problems that made me want to give another solution a shot, and I thought drawing everything on the canvas would be faster and easier!?